# Laravel jobs queue deadlocks with multiple queue daemons

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, queue, database-deadlocks

We have a Laravel 5.2 job queue that frequently fails jobs due to this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

We have multiple workers which access the jobs table because some of the jobs are pretty heavy. I have seen similar posts on SO about this issue but I have yet to see a good practical solution.

Is there an effective way to avoid deadlocks with the Laravel jobs table?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. I put the offending query in a function, and wrapped a try catch when I call the function. I called the function in both try and catch block. so if there is a lock, and an exception is thrown, the catch block will retry the query.